# Atan2 is giving the false angle when object's y or z change in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, angle, atan2

I wrote a algorithm. Its normally working.
Just i can not get right angle of x when y or z changes

```
float x = Mathf.Atan2(transform.forward.y, transform.forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg
```

This code is giving the right angle when my object angles are (x,0,0).
But when the y or z change(x,35,46), this code is giving false angle.
By the way i want to get 0-360 angle.
If i get this angle, code will work(i tested it).
So i am trying to get the rotation of x axis 0-360.
But the atan2 is not giving the right value.
Maybe i can use Vector3.Angle but it doesn't work that i want.
I don't ask too many questions in stackoverflow so if you didn't understand please tell me which part didn't you get it?

Comment: please give example inputs and the fesired outputs

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code rather looks like `c#`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want the objects rotation around the X axis (global or local).

You could probably simply use [`Transform.eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) something like

```
var x = transform.eulerAngles.x;
if(x < 0) angle += 360;
```

Or if you want the local rotation (relative to the parent) [`Transform.localEulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localEulerAngles.html)

```
var x = transform.localEulerAngles.x;
if(x < 0) angle += 360;
```

Comment: Its not working when x is smaller than 270

Comment: Why? What is happening in such case? And where do you see the 270?

Comment: I need to get 0-360 angle eulerAngles is working on 270-90

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't figured out

```
int sign = (transform.forward.y<0) ? 1 : -1;
float x = (Vector3.Angle(transform.position, transform.forward) - 38) * sign * 180 / 100;
```

This code is just working on 0,90,0 angle
I still can not reach the right angle when the rotation change
I found some code with the combination of Cross,Dot,Angle:

```
float Angle360(Vector3 v1, Vector3 v2, Vector3 n)
{
   float angle = Vector3.Angle(v1,v2);
                        
   float sign = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(n, Vector3.Cross(v1, v2)));
   float signed_angle = angle * sign;
                    
   return (signed_angle + 180) % 360;
}
```

This code is not working too
It will be made probably with Vector3.Angle or Dot vs.
How can i find right angle with Vector3.Angle,
The value 38 is changing

```
Vector3.Angle(transform.position, transform.forward)
```

This code is showing the angle but when the rotation change it gives false value.
how can i get the angle of x when objects look change.
So this code is giving right when the value is x,0,0.

```
Mathf.Atan2(transform.forward.y, transform.forward.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg
```

I think i am not using Vector3.Angle Correctly
I need to get the x value when the y and z values are different